# terraform hangs indefinitely when installing provider from local

Tags: terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm

> **What specific commands must we use in order to figure out why terraform hangs indefinitely when it is supposed to be installing `registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.61.0` from a local registry?**

**CURRENT ERROR MESSAGE:**

Here is the error message that terraform writes to the console when it stalls indefinitely/permanently:

```
2021/08/12 13:29:38 [TRACE] providercache.Dir.InstallPackage: installing registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.61.0 from C:\path\to\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\azurerm\2.61.0\windows_amd64
```

I looked in the `C:\path\to\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\azurerm\2.61.0\windows_amd64` directory, and there is indeed an executable named `terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.61.0_x5`.

Also, terraform is set to `TRACE` so that I think we are getting more verbose logs than we would get with `DEBUG`.

We note the extra characters in `terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.61.0_x5` compared to `terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.61.0` , but `terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.61.0_x5` is what terraform installed from the official hashicorp registry when we ran the same module without specifying any local registry using a local `terraform.rc`.  We simply moved the `terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.61.0_x5` that terraform installed into our private local registry at the same path and ran `terraform apply` for the module with a `terraform.rc` pointing to the same executable in the private registry like we do with all our providers, and we got this error result.

What can we do to identify the root cause of this problem?

Comment: Your namespace indicates you are retrieving from a remote registry and not a local registry. It seems that what you may really want is to cache the provider locally to avoid retrieval, which is compatible with the provider namespace that you have specified.

Comment: When looking in the `windows_amd64` directory to find the provider executable Terraform will select any file that has the name prefix `terraform-provider-azurerm`, so the version number and `_x5` suffix, along with `.exe`, are fine and Terraform will ignore them. I don't know what the _actual_ cause is, but I wanted to at least eliminate that from consideration for you. On Windows I'd expect this file to have an `.exe` suffix so that the Windows API can execute it, though I don't know what the effect would be of _not_ including it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard We just copied the providers directory structure from an instance that terraform created when we had our `terraform.rc` removed and then we reinstated our `terraform.rc` to point to the directory into which we copied the providers locally.  This works in all other cases, and is NOT the cause of the current problem.  But are you suggesting that there is a better way to get the providers locally?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Can you point to instructions somewhere on how to create a local registry such as you suggest in your comment above?  We have been copying to a local shared directory the providers that get downloaded when we run `terraform init`, and then we have been pointing `terraform.rc` to that local shared directory.  The resulting local providers then get passed around.  The problem in this OP comes and goes.  We would like to try some automated way to create a local registry if possible, so this becomes more reliable.

Comment: My suggestion was to "point" the Terraform CLI at your locally cached plugins, and not to create a local registry. That would be a first step to fix this issue, and usually resolves it completely.